# Tunneling through ngrok strips wordpress site of styles and theme

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, localhost, ngrok

I have a wordpress site on an IIS at localhost. To demo the site, I used [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to make the site available.

When viewing the site on localhost, everything looks fine. However, when I view the site remotely through the ngrok tunnel, the content appears, but all style & theme elements are lost.

I am not sure what code, configuration or documentation would be helpful for solving this problem.

Any idea why this may be occurring?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your question a bit to make it more readable, so it can be answered more easily. If you are not happy with my edits, feel free to undo them. I would like to ask you to specify the problem. There is developer console in most modern browsers, which displays errors if files can not be loaded. Could you add any errors that might be listed in that console?

Comment: Lars, thank you for the suggestion.  Yes, the error is "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".  I am then guessing this has to do with specific folder permissions, so I am looking at this now.  I will post a solution if I find it.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because the links in wordpress are usually absolute, you need to force Wordpress to use relative URLs with one of those plugins:

https://github.com/optimizamx/odt-relative-urls

http://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/

Comment: If you use odt-relative-urls you don’t even have to change `site_url` or `home` in the options. It worked perfectly for me just by running ngrok and the active odt-relative-urls plugin.